# How to restrict Jenkins access to specific github organization?

Tags: jenkins

We have Jenkins setup in our organisation with two organisational folders which basically does builds for repo's from two different github organizations.

We use Keycloak to authenticate to Jenkins. (Not sure if that's relevant or not) and we authenticate using openid connect with Keycloak.

I would like to know if it is possible to restrict access for a certain group of users to only be able to view builds on one of the github organizations. So for example if we have two github organizations: mrrobot_org and evilcorp_org, then I would like to be able to make an evilcorp_org_devs_group and add users to that group which would then restrict those developers from only accesing builds from the evilcorp_org github organization.

Someone told me this might be possible to do from Keycloak, but it does not seem likely.

I've tried quite a few things already but from what I've read the best option seems to use this plugin
https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/
and match the organzation using a regex to match a folder:"Folders can be matched using expressions like

`^foo/bar.*".`

Any other suggestions how I could do this?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this. I ended up using the Folder auth plugin for Jenkins.
I ended up sticking to Keycloak for Authentication, but used the folder auth plugin for Authorization.
So this allows me to restrict access per Jenkins folder. Each folder containing the builds of a given github organization.

The plugin is pretty easy to use. You can check it out here:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/folder-auth-plugin

The docs are here:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/folder-auth-plugin/blob/master/docs/usage.md